# Split an array inside another in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am trying to write a code that compares two arrays ('a' and 'b)' and do something like that, getting the 'c' array:

a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]

b = [1, 2, 3] (It is taken from 'a' randomly)

c = [2, 3, 5]

The problem I have is very simple since the algorithm is ok.
The code I am using is:

```py
vetor1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
vetor2 = sorted(random.sample(vetor1, 3))
inter = np.intersect1d(vetor1, vetor2)

cont_array2 = []
for i in range(len(inter)):
    cont2 = 0
    for j in range(len(vetor2)):
        if inter[i]==vetor2[j]:
            cont2 = cont2 + 1   
    cont_array2.append(cont2)

cont_array1 = []
for i in range(0,len(inter),1):
    cont1 = 0
    for j in range(0, len(vetor1), 1):
        if inter[i]==vetor1[j]:
            cont1 = cont1 + 1   
    cont_array1.append(cont1)

n_elements = np.subtract(cont_array1, cont_array2)

vetor2_1 = []
for i in range(len(n_elements)):
    if n_elements[i]!=0:
        vetor2_1.append(inter[i]*np.ones(n_elements[i]))

vetor2_2 = []
for data1 in vetor1:
    if data1 not in inter:
        vetor2_2.append(data1)

vetor3 = sorted(vetor2_1 + vetor2_2)
print(vetor3)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[array([2.]), array([3.]), 5]
```

I imagine the problem is in:

```py
vetor2_1.append(inter[i]*np.ones(n_elements[i]))
```

Because:

```py
print(vetor2_1)
```

Gives me:

```
[array([2.]), array([3.])]
```

What should I do since I am not receving as answer [2, 3, 5]?

Comment: And what should this piece of code be doing?

Comment: The idea is to receive a sample, resample it randomly and, comparing the two arrays, take to a new one what is in the original sample that it's not in the resample array.

Comment: There isn't a way of doing this using mostly NumPy methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can turn all your algorithm into one line:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]

b = [1, 2, 3]

c = [a.pop(a.index(i)) for i in b] #Works even with strings.
```

### Output:

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

If you need to parametrize something, you can turn it into a function. This will work with  `sorted(random.sample(vetor1, 3))`, but I didn't use it for replicability.

Comment: WOW, thank you. I should have come here first after cracking my head to write this one. Amazed.

Comment: It's always a good exercise to crack your head first and if it doesn't work, ask for help. That way you'll get better at problem solving which is the main skill you'll need to be a good coder (:. Also could you mark the answer as the accepted one, so it doesn't remain open? Thanks

Comment: but there is a problem: I need to use it for continuous variables, then, how should I proceed?

Comment: if `a` is actually continuous, then  how do you draw `b` out of `a` ?

Comment: ``a`` is an array with continuous variables, like a = [1.2, 3.4, ...]. By using this code you sent, we get float indexes after taking randomly veriables from ``a``.

Comment: Thank you, Juan. You are amazing!

Comment: Juan, I was using the code and got a problem. I tought it was working but it is not. When I call: 
```python
[a.pop(a.index(i)) for i in b]
```
It is returning the same b array.

Comment: Instead, I used this: 
```python
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [a.index(i) for i in b]

for element in sorted(c, reverse = True):  
    del a[element]
print(c)
print(a)
```
output:
```python
[0, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: What's the output you're looking for? `[2,3,5]` ? Are you sure you checked `a` instead of `b`?

Answer (score 0):

```
//generating a random index for array a, to take 3 elements out of it
my_random_int = random.randint(0,len(a)-2)

//popping the element out of the array to put them in b

for x in range(0,2):
    b[x]=a.pop(my_random_int+x)
```

sources:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop

https://www.edureka.co/blog/generate-random-number-in-python/